# XAMPP - Localhost 404 Object Not Found error

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am trying to install Open EMR on my system and when I try to open Localhost, I get the 404 error. Details are given below

- XAMPP 3.2.1
- Windows 8.1 64bit
- Open EMR 4.2.0
- Apache and MySQL are started in XAMPP control panel

Can someone please help?

Comment: Are you placing the files in the right location? What URL are you using?

Comment: When you place a test.php with `<?php echo '12345';` in the (alleged) htdocs directory can you request it?